# Push is overwriting previous data in array

Tags: javascript

I'm passing a string which looks something like: "John.Doe.100.Newbie-David.Miller.250.Veteran-" to the SplitDatabase function which splits the string appropriately and assigns the values to the UserDataEntry object. The UserDataEntry object is then pushed in to the global UserData array which is supposed to store all the user data.

For some reason though, the UserData.push(UserDataEntry) part seems to be overwriting previous data in the UserData array. The alert in the 1st loop shows the correct data as it loops, but alert in the second loop at the bottom just shows the last record over and over again.

I'm not sure why this is?

```
var UserData = [];


function SplitDatabase(result) {
    var RawUsers = result.split('-');
    var UserDataEntry = {};


    for (var i = 0; i < (RawUsers.length - 1); i++) {
        var tempUserData = RawUsers[i].split('.');
        for (var x = 0; x < (tempUserData.length); x++) {

            switch (x) {
            case 0:
                UserDataEntry.firstname = tempUserData[x];
                break;
            case 1:
                UserDataEntry.lastname = tempUserData[x];
                break;
            case 2:
                UserDataEntry.points = tempUserData[x];
                break;
            case 3:
                UserDataEntry.rank = tempUserData[x];
                UserData.push(UserDataEntry);
                alert(UserData[i].firstname);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < (UserData.length); i++) {  
        alert(UserData[i].firstname);
    }

}
```

Comment: clear array before writing new data!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Calling `push` will not copy your object, because JavaScript `Object`s are passed by reference: you're pushing the same `Object` as every array entry.

You can fix this easily by moving the `var UserDataEntry = {};` *inside* the loop body, so that a new object is created each loop iteration:

```
    for (var x = 0; x < (tempUserData.length); x++) {
         var UserDataEntry = {};
```

Comment: The block defined by the braces of the loop doesn't generate it's own scope; the `var UserDataEntry;` can be in the same place. The important bit to have in the loop is just the `UserDataEntry = {}`, which creates a new object and so a new reference.

Comment: Who thought such things could be nightmare for coders 

Comment: What if I need to use `UserDataEntry` out side of function... for this case, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 12):

Put your line `var UserDataEntry = {}` inside the for loop.

Right now, you only have one object, and you're setting each part of the array to that object.  You overwrite the members in your loop.

If you create a new object inside the loop, you'll add all new members in to the array.