# Push object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I need to push object to array in Javascript, but every time push overwrite the same object I have had already added. For example:

```
//This is object list
var NewIssue = {};
//This is array
var newIssueList = [];

function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        NewIssue.Id = i;
        NewIssue.Number = 233 + i;
        NewIssue.Name = "Test" + i.toString();

        newIssueList.push(NewIssue);
    }
}
```

In the end I will have newIssueList with 3 same objects. Why it does overwrite the first and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Add `NewIssue = {};` to the top of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push is overwriting previous data in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054997/push-is-overwriting-previous-data-in-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to move the object inside the loop.

```js
var newIssueList = [];

function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var NewIssue = {};
        NewIssue.Id = i;
        NewIssue.Number = 233 + i;
        NewIssue.Name = "Test" + i.toString();

        newIssueList.push(NewIssue);
    }
}

myFunction();

console.log(newIssueList);
```

And then you could just extend the object literal a but to make it much more readable:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var NewIssue = {
           Id:i,
           Number:233+i,
           Name:"Test"+i
        };

        newIssueList.push(NewIssue);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid using a superfluous var by creating an inline object:

```
newIssueList.push({
    Id: i,
    Number: 233 + i,
    Name: "Test" + i.toString()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is only one object, and each time you push it into the array, you push a reference to the existing object. When you change the object, every element in the array reflects this, as they all point to the same object.

You need to create a new object on every iteration.

```js
//This is array
var newIssueList = [];

function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newIssueList.push({
      id: i,
      number: 233 + i,
      name: "Test" + i.toString()
    });
  }
}

myFunction();

console.log(newIssueList);
```