# Why .push() replacing the last object of JSON array?

Tags: json, node.js, angular, http, express

I have developed an Angular4 basic CRUD application that interacts with a nodejs backend API that renders data of a JSON array. But on adding an object to the JSON array using .push() method it replaces the last object with the new to be added object instead of pushing it to the array.

The following is the definition of Employee :

```
export interface Employee {
id:number,
name:string,
review:string[],
peers:string[]
}
```

The service method makes the HTTP call is following:

```
addEmployee(addedEmployee:Employee):Observable<Response>
{
return 
this._http.post("http://localhost:3001/add",addedEmployee)
.pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

The backend API code that adds an Employee object to JSON object array is following:

```
app.post('/add',function(req,res){
var addedEmployee={};
addedEmployee.id=req.body.id;
addedEmployee.name=req.body.name;
addedEmployee.review=req.body.review;
addedEmployee.peers=req.body.peers;
employees.push(addedEmployee);
console.log('added');
res.json(employees);
})
```

The before, intermediate and after structures of the  backend JSON object array are following:

Before:

```
employees = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe",
    review: ["Hardworking"],
    peers: ["admin", "Matt"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Matt Hofner",
    review: ["Hardworking"],
    peers: ["admin"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Judy Ruth",
    review: ["Focused"],
    peers: ["admin", "Matt"]
}
];
```

Intermediate:

```
let addedEmployee:Employee = {
  id: 4,
  name: "Trudy",
    review:["Lazy"],
    peers: ["Matt"]
  };
```

Final :

```
employees = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "John Doe",
    review: ["Hardworking"],
    peers: ["admin", "Matt"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Matt Hofner",
    review: ["Hardworking"],
    peers: ["admin"]
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "Trudy",
    review: ["Lazy"],
    peers: ["Matt"]
}
];
```

Comment: where is employees being declared or fetched ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054997/push-is-overwriting-previous-data-in-array

Comment: Just tried to do a push in browser console and it works properly..  How's the employee array being declared in first place? as var employee = new Array[3] ? or inline initialization as in the code snippet ?

Comment: employees array has been declared in another file which has been imported in the backend script. And the declaration is inline as in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. This might not be the best solution but try the .concat() method :

```
app.post('/add',function(req,res){
var addedEmployee={};
var singleEmployeeArray = [];
addedEmployee.id=req.body.id;
addedEmployee.name=req.body.name;
addedEmployee.review=req.body.review;
addedEmployee.peers=req.body.peers;
singleEmployeeArray.push(addedEmployee);
employees.concat(singleNewEmployeeArray);
console.log('added');
res.json(employees);
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but  .concat() is also showing the same result.