# Make new object with an array for each

Tags: javascript

I want to make 3 news object from an array with forEach method and push it into an new array. But the result in new array alway the last element in old array.  Sorry for my silly question.Thank you so much

```
let A =['0','1','2'];
let C = {};
let D = [];
A.forEach( a => {
    C['name'] = a;
    D.push(C)
    print(D[a]['name']);
});

   print(D[0]['name']);
     print(D[1]['name']);
     print(D[2]['name']);

0
1
2
2
2
2
```

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. You don’t have multiple _different_ `C` objects pushed into `D` here, you have pushed the _same_ object multiple times.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you're using `.forEach()`? Imo that should be [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push is overwriting previous data in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054997/push-is-overwriting-previous-data-in-array)

Comment: what out put you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are reference type so they are passed by reference. However, you can create new object and push it into array:

```js
let A = ['0', '1', '2'];
let C = {};
let D = [];
A.forEach(name => {
  D.push({name});
});

console.log(D);
```

Comment: Shnick changed the name of the property for you.

Answer (score 0):

To keep  your reasoning you can use :

```
let A = ['0', '1', '2'];
let C = {};
let D = [];
A.forEach(a => {
  C['name'] = a;
  D=Object.assign({}, C)
});

console.log(D);
```