# Push an array of objects by it's value to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am getting unexpected results from my below program. Both `inputs` and `outputs` arrays are getting same value. Somehow from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054997/push-is-overwriting-previous-data-in-array) I got to know that it's the problem of passing a reference. My question is how can I achieve the same with below approach. Appreciate your time.

> Expecting inputs array to be `[[{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}], [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}]]`

```js
var inputs = [];
var outputs = [];
var exampleArr = [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}];

function analyze(listArr) {
    inputs.push(...listArr);

    outputs = [...outputs, ...listArr];

    outputs.forEach((item) => {
        item.name = 'hello';
    });

    console.log('inputs', inputs);
    console.log('ouputs', outputs);
    listArr.pop();
    if(listArr.length) analyze(listArr);
}

analyze(exampleArr);
```

Comment: The objects inside the array are also passed by reference. Try using the spread operator against those. I can't really help you more on that one, what you are trying to do is very unclear to me.

Comment: Thanks @JulienB. I am trying to record all the inputs coming to my recursive function and then build the output by merging with input. BTW how can I use spread operator against objects.

Comment: Well, you can do something like ...item but then it is going to be another object thus not updating the one in your output. Maybe you should try adding it to the output after you changed it. And, I don't know if this is the real code or you are trying to caviar but those loops spread and calling back the analyze function altogether, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry I am not authorised to post my code here. So I tried to create a similar issue with help of above snippet. In real code, I am finding a tree of depended modules through a recursive call and with each call I am storing inputs in 2D array to print when recursive call ends. This inputs array and it's corresponding objects should not change what ever I do after pushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone all objects in listArr (one nesting level only) before appending to outputs.

```js
var inputs = [];
var outputs = [];
var exampleArr = [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}];

function analyze(listArr) {
    inputs.push(...listArr);

    // clone objects in array, one level
    outputs = [...outputs, ...listArr.map(x=>typeof x==='object'? {...x}:x)];

    outputs.forEach((item) => {
        item.name = 'hello';
    });

    console.log('inputs', inputs);
    console.log('ouputs', outputs);
    listArr.pop();
    if(listArr.length) analyze(listArr);
}

analyze(exampleArr);
```

Comment: In my case it's always an object but without typeof operator it's not working.

Comment: probably syntax problem: `.map(x=> ({...x}) )` without parens it interprets it as function body

Comment: Thank you... But I am not able understand why my question got -ve vote.

Comment: Don't know.  If a person feels as if the question's clarity or quality wasted too much of their time (or they feel insufficient effort was shown on the posters part), or if the question doesn't have lasting value for SO for future visitors, they will downvote it.  This is the way SO is supposed to be designed, so that high quality results get pushed to the top.  I wouldn't worry too much about it.