# Array OverWrite itself by pushing Objects (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

So here comes my problem: In my opinion it's a very simple problem to solve but i don't know why this is happening; well as my title say my array is overwriting itself giving as output a 7 Object's Array

Here is the code, i've put some console.log() for you to see what i'm meaning:

```js
let str = "100 23 20 99 92 123 88";
let arr = str.split(" ");
console.log(arr);
console.log("\n");
var aObj={};
let arrS=[];
console.log(arrS);
for (let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
  let sum=0;
  for (let j=0; j<arr[i].length;j++){
     sum += parseInt(arr[i][j]);
  }
  aObj.value=sum;
  aObj.strI=arr[i];
  console.log(aObj);
  console.log("\n");
  arrS.push(aObj);
  console.log(arrS);
  console.log("\n");
}
```

https://repl.it/@Arcall95/try#index.js

[image: Repl.it console.log() output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relevant: [Push is overwriting previous data in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054997/push-is-overwriting-previous-data-in-array)

Every iteration of the loop, what you're doing is changing the properties of a single object `aObj` and pushing it to `arrS`.

Instead, you should be creating a new object for each iteration by pulling `var aObj={}` inside the loop.

Comment: thank your for the answer it's been really helpful, didn't know objects where passed by reference!!

Comment: Happy to help! :)