# unexpected values being pushed onto array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am having, what I believe to be, weird behaviour while trying to push onto an array. I see expected values when outputting the array. If I push onto the array and then output, I get repeated values. The code in question:

```
var test = "aab";
testA = test.split("");
permutations = [];
generatePermutations(testA, testA.length);

function generatePermutations(array, arrayLength) {
        if (arrayLength === 1) {
        console.log(array); // THIS OUTPUTS DIFFERENT PERMUTATIONS
        permutations.push(array);
        console.log(permutations); // VALUES IN ARRAY ARE ALL THE SAME

        /* 
          permutations.push(array.join(""));
          console.log(permutations);
          SPLITTING THE STRING MAKES IT WORK FINE?!
        */ 
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i += 1) {
        generatePermutations(array, arrayLength - 1);

        if (arrayLength % 2 == 0) {
            swapArrayElements(array, i, arrayLength - 1);
        } else {
            swapArrayElements(array, 0, arrayLength - 1);
        }
    }
}

function swapArrayElements(array, elementA, elementB) {
    var temp = array[elementA];
    array[elementA] = array[elementB];
    array[elementB] = temp;
}
```

`console.log(array)` will output a permutation as expected. It will output all permutations as the function recurs:

> [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ] [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ] [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ] [ 'a', 'b', 'a'
>   ] [ 'a', 'b', 'a' ] [ 'b', 'a', 'a' ]

If I push the result onto another array, `permutations.push(array)`, every element has the same value:

> [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ],   [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ],   [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ],   [
>   'a', 'a', 'b' ],   [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ],   [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ] ]

I get the expected result if I join the array whilst pushing it onto permutations: `permutations.push(array.join("")):

> [ 'aab', 'aab', 'baa', 'aba', 'aba', 'baa' ]

what am I missing here? I cannot understand how array can contain a value that all of a sudden changes upon being pushed onto permutations.

For clarity, this is a freecodecamp task and I'm working towards finding non repeating permutations.

Comment: Because you are pushing the same array over and over. If you want a snapshot of the array, push a copy that you never change thereafter.

Comment: I'm sure I am being dense here, but: I understand what you're saying but I don't see how I'm doing that. All I see is me pushing array onto permutations. If array is "this is a string" and on the next time round "this is also a string" surely permutations is going to end up being: ["this is a string", this is also a string"] and so on?

Comment: Arrays are reference types. You are pushing multiple references to the same array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript pushing objects into array changes entire array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217188/javascript-pushing-objects-into-array-changes-entire-array)

Comment: argh, I knew this. Dense I am. Thank you Mr Chen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same *array* variable, which always references the same memory location. So whatever you change in that array, is changed independent of whether you access the array via *array* or via *permutations*, which has all its elements set to the same array reference.

You can solve this by adding copies of the arrays to the *permutations* array, like so:

```
permutations.push(array.slice(0));
```

Note that the *array* values you have consist of strings. If they were mutable objects which you also modified, then you would need to extend this solution further. But in your case the above is enough.

Comment: so unbelievably obvious. gar! Thanks.